# SharePoint workflow + infopath form

Tags: 2007, infopath

Hi 
I would like to design a workflow in SharePoint2010.Requirements are

```
1.  I need to attach a custom workflow with InfoPath form library.

2.  I need to save the incomplete  form to the library , when I do this ,it will not kick off the workflow.

3. When user complete the form and submits the form to the form library , it will trigger the workflow.

4. When the workflow starts ,I need to send an  email to  selected user .This email will include a link which directs the user to the form in SharePoint.

5. It might also requires to attach the form to the email so that the user can open the form using InfoPath filler and then save to the SharePoint form library.
```

My question is that

1. Can this be achieved by using SharePoint designer and if so , how can I deploy this into the production server?
2. How can I make sure when saving the incomplete form will not kick off  the workflow, while submitting the form will kick off the workflow.
3. How can I get the link that points to the current form in the form library?

I am pretty new to SharePoint workflow , can anyone give me some advice on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All but your 5th requirement can be done using SPD.
You can attach a WF to any library, so an InfoPath library shouldn't be a problem.

You just have to add some status field in your form (hidden) with a status number to see if the form is completed or not. If the form is submitted as 'final' you'll just flip the status number to '2' for example.
You'll let the workflow check on created and changed files, so it'll notice every change in files. This means the WF will start always when a changes is made. You just have to add some logic it quits directly if the status isn't '2' (or some other number).

Be sure to change the number once the WF enters the real logic, otherwise when another change is made, it could start all over again.

Comment: How can I get the link that points to the current form in the form library? and how about deploy a SPD workflow to production?